# Testing Camel REST DSL Consumer Template

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-camel, dsl

I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;

public class OrderNumberRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)          
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .contextPath("suppliera/rest").port(8080);

        rest("/ordernumber").description("ordernumber rest service")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")

            .get("/{id}").description("get ordernumber").outType(ServiceResponse.class)
            .to("bean:orderNumberService?method=getOrderNumber(${header.id})");
    }
}
```

How can I use JUnit to test this code? Can `CamelTestSupport` handle it?

I want to create a test like:

```
@Produce(------myendpoint----) 
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer; 

public void mytest(){
testProducer.requestBody("foo");
}
```

how can I mock that? what I put in -----myendpoint---- to reference that route?

Comment: JUnit will test the code locally on your system, before it's deployed to wildfly.

Comment: If you have a test in progress, please edit your question and add the source so we can see what else you need. :)

Comment: My solution for this problem was to remove the java code and passes it to the  `spring.xml` to not reduce my code coverage, so I tested only the  `bean`.
I'm still looking for a way to test the `REST DSL` route, but thanks for help @Barett

Answer (score 4):

As a possible solution, you can set the URI for your REST route and use that URI in your junit test. In order to do so, you need to switch RestDefinition to RouteDefinition by calling *route* method, and then you can call the *from* method and set the uri argument.
Example using direct endpoint:

```
    rest("/ordernumber").description("ordernumber rest service")
    .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
    .get("/{id}").description("get ordernumber").outType(ServiceResponse.class)
    .route().from("direct:myendpoint")
    .to("bean:orderNumberService?method=getOrderNumber(${header.id})");
```

In your junit class, you can then type:

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:myendpoint")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: though it may be a workaround, but Its meaningless to modify the source code for the ease of developing testcase (what if the route definition resides in some depepndency?). Though I am not sure but still I think there must be some other/proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the examples on this page? https://camel.apache.org/testing.html

Since you have Spring, try the Spring test examples on that page. Those will be more appropriate for your situation than using `CamelTestSupport`.

Comment: It's my first time using rest, i want to do something like it:
@Produce(direct:myRestEndpoint)
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;

testProducer.requestBody("foo");


but i dont know how to get the rest endpoint or mock it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom RestConsumerFactory to be used in test.
If you are using spring create a bean of type RestConsumerFactory like

```java
public class TestRestConsumerFactory implements RestConsumerFactory {

    @Override
    public Consumer createConsumer(CamelContext camelContext, Processor processor, String verb, String basePath, String uriTemplate, String consumes, String produces, RestConfiguration configuration, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {

        // just use a direct endpoint for testing purpose
        String id;
        if (uriTemplate != null) {
            id = DefaultUuidGenerator.generateSanitizedId(basePath + uriTemplate);
        } else {
            id = DefaultUuidGenerator.generateSanitizedId(basePath);
        }
        // remove leading dash as we add that ourselves
        if (id.startsWith("-")) {
            id = id.substring(1);
        }

        DirectEndpoint direct = camelContext.getEndpoint("direct:" + verb + "-" + id, DirectEndpoint.class);
        return direct.createConsumer(processor);
    }
}
```

Code inspired by [Camel test](https://github.com/DjSystemBPM/Camel/blob/master/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter/camel-core-starter/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/model/rest/springboot/CamelRestTest.java)

If you are using spring, you can crate a bean in test config

```java
@Bean
public RestConsumerFactory testRestConsumerFactory(){
   return new TestRestConsumerFactory();
}
```

Otherwise set it explicitely to the camel rest configuration.
Camel will find it and use as Rest component see Camel documentation: [Camel REST DSL documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html)

```
If no component has been explicit configured, then Camel will lookup if there is a Camel component that integrates with the Rest DSL, or if a org.apache.camel.spi.RestConsumerFactory is registered in the registry. If either one is found, then that is being used.
```

This custom RestConsumerFactory replaces rest endpoints to direct endpoints e.g.

GET /say/hello -> direct:get-say-hello

so you can then use them in your test code

```java
testProducer.requestBody("direct:get-say-hello", "body");
```

**Bonus**

In case you have parametrised endpoint, RestConsumerFactory implemented above will replace it using curly braces e.g.

GET /say/{word} -> direct:get-say-{word}

You can still test such endpoint setting appropriate header

```java
Map<String, Object> headers = ImmutableMap.of("word", "hello");
producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:get-say-{word}", null, headers);
```